# Azure Service Bus without a config file

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I need to send messages to a topic in Azure, but I can't have a config file (Long story short, I'm writing a plugin for an app that only allows dlls).

I've tried TopicClient.CreateFromConnectionString and using a MessageFactory, but they through an exception:

> The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ServiceBus.RelayEnvironment' threw
>   an exception.

With an inner exception of:

> Path is not of a legal format.

Does anyone know how to create a topic or queue client without having a config file?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me..

```
 var serviceBusConnectionString =
            "Endpoint=sb://myhost/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=mykey";
        var serviceBusTopicPath = "mytopicname";

        var factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(serviceBusConnectionString);

        var sender = factory.CreateTopicClient(serviceBusTopicPath);
        sender.Send(new BrokeredMessage("hello"));
```